# How do we prove $\forall t>f(x),\exists\delta>0,\forall y\in$ dom($f$), $|y-x|<\delta\implies f(y)<t$ if and only if the following condition?

Tags: calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta, limsup-and-liminf

How do we prove $\forall t>f(x),\exists\delta>0,\forall y\in$ dom($f$), $|y-x|<\delta\implies f(y)<t$ if and only if (whenever a sequence $s_n$ of points in dom $(f)$ converges to $x$, we have $\lim\sup f(s_n)\le f(x)$)?

we know the definition of $\lim\sup s_n=l$ is that $\forall t>l, \exists N, n>N\implies s_n<t$.

The $\le$ really stops me from going. Could someone help?

Comment: You have defined limsup incorrectly. Take the sequence {1,1,1,...}. According to your definition, 100 would be a limsup of that sequence. What you have is an implication of limsup but not a definition.

Comment: Use the definition that limsup is the sup of all the subsequential limits if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with: Whenever a sequence $s_n$ of points in dom $(f)$ converges to $x$, we have $\lim\sup f(s_n)\le f(x)$

Suppose there exists  $ t>f(x)$, such that $\forall\delta>0$,$\exists y\in$ dom($f$), $|y-x|<\delta$ and $ f(y)\geq t$

Then you can have a sequence of $y_n$s converging to $x$, such that $f(y_n)\geq t>f(x) \forall n$, which brings a contradiction to $\limsup f(y_n)\le f(x)$.

Now can you go the other way?

Hint for the other direction:

Suppose, $\forall t>f(x)$,$\exists\delta^*>0$ such that $\forall y\in$ dom($f$), $|y-x|<\delta$, we have $f(y)<t$

Pick any $t>f(x)$. Now take a sequence of points in domain of $f$ that converge to $x$, i.e, $s_n \to x$. There would exist $N$ such that $|s_n-x |<\delta^*\ \  \forall n\geq N$.

Using what is given, $f(s_n)<t\ \  \forall n\geq N$. Now use the definition of limsup to get your proof? Use the definition that limsup is the sup of all the subsequential limits if you want.

Comment: How does $f(y_n)>f(x)$ contradicts $\lim\sup f(y_n)\le f(x)?$

Comment: For the forward direction, we know $s_n\rightarrow x$, this $\lim\sup s_n=x$, thus $\forall T=\delta + x>x,\exists N, n>N\implies s_n<T\implies|s_n-x|<\delta\implies f(s_n)<t$, this $t$ I don't know how to deal with, also the $\le$ confuses me of definition of $\lim\sup f(s_n)\le f(x)$

Comment: Provided more hints.

Comment: the definition of $\lim\sup f(s_n)$is that $\forall t>\lim\sup f(s_n), \exists N, n>N\implies f(s_n)<t$, how is it possible we use the later to get the earlier?

Comment: I think I got it, since $f(s_n)<t$ for all $n$, so $t$ is upper bound, then $\lim\sup f(s_n)<t$, since it's for any $t>f(x)$, we have $\lim\sup f(s_n)<f(x)$, right?

Comment: In fact $\limsup f(s_n) \leq t$ for all $t>f(x)$. Take a limit of t's converging to f(x) and you are done with what you said.

Comment: Take a limit of $t$? How is it converging to $x$?

Comment: I mean take a sequence of t's converging to *$f(x) $*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.